# Flask + Jinja: Pass Data to a Base Template/All Templates

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a method that returns data which is needed in my base template (content for a global footer).

How do either (1) pass a variable into the base template (which other templates extend) or (2) pass a variable to all templates globally without explicitly adding it in a call to `render_template`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From flask docs: [Flask's Context Processors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/templating/#context-processors)

> To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template,
> context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the
> template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into
> the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a
> dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged
> with the template context, for all templates in the app:

Example from docs:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user():
    return dict(user=g.user)
```

Note that this example uses the `g` variable, which is already accessible in templates.

Comment: But this would add to all templates right? What if I wanted to add only in certain views?