# How to send Flask data to HTML without having to assign it to each individual render_template?

Tags: flask, jinja2

The normal way of sending data to HTML that I know of is

```
data = ['a','b','c']
return render_template('index.html', my_data=data)
```

However, say I have 10+ routes that I have to keep track of, is there a more efficient way to globally send `data` to every route without having to explicitly say so in every instance of `render_template()`?

The reason for this is I have used Auth0 to create the login, now I have the user_info which contains their name and display picture, etc, this gets stored in the `session['profile']`. It'd be nice to send this information to every route so that I can display

```
IMG | Username | [log out]
```

In the Navbar on every page, without having to include it in the render template method every time for every instance. Is there something like this?

Comment: You need a context processor, first Google result for "flask include data in every template": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498689/flask-jinja-pass-data-to-a-base-template-all-templates

Comment: @boreq cheers, that worked.