# Flask layout template form how to get post/get request. Route layout?

Tags: python, flask, layout, flask-wtforms

I'm making a customer support popup bot in Flask. I added the customer support popup bot to the layout template in the base.html file so that it appears on all of the routes.

In the customer support bot it has a form to get user input, but I can't figure out a way to get the post/get request from the bot. Since the bot is not in the views route.

I am not sure how to send and get info to my `layout/customer_support.html` page. Since the page is not rendering constantly.

Any advice on how to send the info back and retrieve the info from my `layout/customer_support.html` bot would be much appreciated thanks

EDIT: I'm aware of context manager, but now sure how to get the post/get information from my `layout/customer_support.html` form with the context manger. Am I suppose to somehow route the layout to get post/get request?

Some link I tried
[Flask + Jinja: Pass Data to a Base Template/All Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498689/flask-jinja-pass-data-to-a-base-template-all-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a session like:

```
import from flask_session import Session
```

And then create a session function

```
def session_support(chat):

    if "support" not in session:
       session["support"] = []
    else:
       session["support"].append(chat)
```

This might work somehow...